# Simple jQuery and Knockout.js Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm going through [this tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) on the `knockout.js` website. I'm running into an issue on Step 2 out of 5.

There's one block of code that is this:

```
// Data
var self = this;
self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
self.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();

// Behaviours    
self.goToFolder = function(folder) { 
    self.chosenFolderId(folder);
    $.get('/mail', { folder: folder }, self.chosenFolderData);
};
```

My issue is, I don't get how jQuery is handling the third argument of `$.get`. To my knowledge (and from reading [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType)), the third argument is  a success function. However, `self.chosenFolderData` doesn't seem to be that.

Any insight into why this is working?

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html says "....ko.observable objects are actually functions...." I don't know knockout, but I would guess based on that (from 2 seconds of googling) that if you return an observable, you actually return a reference to a function which can then, as in this case, be provided as a callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.chosenFolderData` **is** a function: All KO observables are functions; [details in the KO docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html). When you call an observable and pass in an argument, you set the value of the observable. That's exactly what `get` will do with the success callback.

---

Side note:

> To my knowledge (and from reading the docs), the third argument is a success function.

The success callback isn't necessarily the third thing you pass. It is in the example you've quoted, but it isn't necessarily. It could be the second, or if you don't pass any success callback, the third could be `dataType`.

The signature shown for `jQuery.get` in the docs is:

```
jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

The `[...]` indicate optional arguments. That means you can do any of seven different combinations of things:

```
jQuery.get( url )
jQuery.get( url , data )
jQuery.get( url , data , success )
jQuery.get( url , success 
jQuery.get( url , success , dataType )
jQuery.get( url , data , dataType )
jQuery.get( url , data , success , dataType )
```